# can a C# windows application be run on a windows 8 based tablet well?

Tags: c#, windows-8, tablet

Recently I was asked to work on a project which was developed for an aviculture company.
The client asked if I can make the application which was being developed in C#, to work on a tablet.
So i want to know if i finish the application in c# normally Will I be able to:
1.Use the `mono for android` and compile the whole project with that and get an android app easily for being used in android devices?
2.Use the executable project on a Windows 8 tablet without any changes?
I would be grateful if any one could answer these two questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends which tablet you're talking about.

- On a Windows RT (ARM based) tablet like Surface, only Metro apps are supported. There are a few desktop apps, but only Microsoft can make them. So if your app is a desktop app, it won't run on Surface RT.
- On a tablet with the "real" Windows 8 (x86 based, e.g. Surface Pro), you can run the same apps as on a PC.

Comment: so if i use sql  in my app there is no problem right? its just like pc for real?

Comment: @Hossein, it has nothing to do with SQL; it depends on whether your app is a "Windows Store app" (aka Metro app) or a desktop app. Regarding databases, ADO.NET is not available in Metro apps, so you can't use the usual means of connecting to a database. You need to use a webservice or a local SQLite database.

Comment: so we cant have desktop apps on windows 8 at all?!and my application needs to be metro styled !? What if i dont want to place my app on MS App Store?Are other ways of installing apps on an windows 8 tablets rather than appstore?

Comment: @Hossein, you can have desktop apps on Windows 8, not on Windows RT (which is the ARM version of Windows 8)

Comment: By windows 8 i meant real windows 8 (as you have pointed out it yourself) not the RT verion.,I have no business with it as it only seems to be just a name!