# WPF .exe application file is not working in Windows 8 surface Tablet

Tags: wpf, deployment, windows-8.1, windows-rt

Am new to WPF .Previously was worked with Windows 8 /Windows phone application developer.  I created a List application using `ListBox` in WPF. Since i wanted to test the application on a touch device i tried to run it's `.exe` file on my Windows 8 Surface tablet. I could not run my application.

Can't I run WPF application on Windows 8 tablet? Currently am working & running it using a Windows 8 PC , Where it runs. Please provide any information regarding this.

Or how we can create my application's package so that we could run it on Windows 8 surface tablet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Surface Pro tablets, you should still be able to run WPF.  However, the standard tablets will only run [Store Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/).

Comment: my tablet is WinRT Surface 32GB. So what about it?

Comment: @asitis to the best of my knowledge, RT tablets will only run RT programs (i.e. store apps)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842592/can-a-c-sharp-windows-application-be-run-on-a-windows-8-based-tablet-well. Another interesting read is http://blogs.computerworld.com/windows/23194/microsoft-confirms-windows-rt-will-die. This make sense as there are some nice Atom based tablets that will run WPF desktop applications and they are cheaper than Surface RT.