# WPF application touch response on Win8 tablet

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8

I have a WPF application written for desktop. When I run the application on a non-touch win8 pc, the tab change, combobox drop down etc work fine. The same application on a Win8 tab is behaving differently. The tab changes after a delay. The response of the UI is slower comparitively. I tried implementing this piece on code in my MainWindow constructor from this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230087(v=vs.110).aspx). But the application crashes when I open child windows.

I am running the application on a Windows 8 pro tablet with Intel Atom. So it's not WinRT and allows desktop apps to run.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903982/wpf-exe-application-file-is-not-working-in-windows-8-surface-tablet

Comment: tablet is usually no match to desktop in terms of hardware Spec. But this also suggest that the WPF application has performance issue (can't run smoothly on 1GB mem, 1GHz CPU)

Comment: @kennyzx: I have 2 GB RAM and 1.8 GHz processor on the tablet.